# uncompressing xml feed gzip deflate php

Tags: php, xml, gzip, deflate

I am being sent an XML feed which needs to be downloaded in a 'compressed way'.

The example I have been given is this:

```
$url = 'http://myurl.com';
$headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

but the output I am getting is jargon like this:

��+T����s�ƒ-�}#���;}�w7f���d]K�F��x���HB$�&����G�����6������IW���Y��'�����߷��sR,�<������ �.��4���֫�'��������?''^�?9��;��*�9^|����>'�j�~���ǫ�}z��|���h���q���J����Գ"�.o������2)~���bU���~������I|

How to a convert it back into XML?

Many thanks

Comment: You need to provide a clue as to what language or environment you are operating in.  If not in the question, at least in the tags.

Comment: Did you try running `gzdecode` on the returned data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gzinflate() to inflate a deflated string
gzdeflate() works in reverse.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php